# Node routes for authenticated area?

Tags: node.js, authentication, routes

We have an app with the following routes

```
/dothis/
    ...//dothis routes
/dothat
    ...//dothat routes
/doother
    ...//doother routes
```

and a login route:

```
/login
```

and

```
/   //which currently actually isn't even used, would redirect to /login
```

Is it possible to close the routes so that actually only / and /login are accessible without authentication? Or do we need to apply a prefix to all other routes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
   app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
         //  console.log(everyauth);
        if (!req.session.auth) {
            res.redirect('/login');
        } else {
          next();
        }
    });

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login', {
  });
});
```

seems to work

Answer (score 0):

```
app.all('*', Authentication, function(req, res) {
});

function Authentication(req, res, next) {
   if (req is not user) {
       if (req.url === '/' || req.url === '/login')
           next()
   }
   else
      next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have middleware which does exactly this: https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login

```
app.get('/dothat',
  ensureLoggedIn('/login'),  // redirect to /login if not logged in
  function(req, res) {
    // render do that;
  });
```

It's usable stand-alone, but also integrates seamlessly with [Passport](http://passportjs.org/), so that after login, the user will be redirected back to the URL they originally requested.